# Compiling and building a C file from a C program

Tags: c, compilation, system, system-calls, xv6

I was wondering that if it is possible to compile and build, and eventually run a C file from another C file (This C file would eventually be a system call file).

i.e.

```
...
// Calling gcc(?) or something to compile and build the executable 
/* running the executable */
// Executable ends and return to this file
...
```

Is there any C functions that can do this?

Comment: Yes of course there is a way, but why do you want to do this? Are you familiar with the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: Yes, of course you can do this. If you decompose the problem, and then search for ways to solve individual tasks, you'll see that it is trivial to execute an external program in C (e.g. `system()`).

Comment: @iharob I am implementing a system call, that would take in a C file, and executes the file, then returning some data to the system call for calculation.

Comment: @thedarkguy That is not the way [tag:c] should be used. You can't rely on the result of that idea. You write a program, and then you compile it and run it. If you want some kind of [tag:c] interpreter you are trying to do something that will not work well IMHO.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I know that `system()` runs the executable or is it? But how can I gcc it? Do I go with `exec()` while finding the path to the gcc executable? I am currently working it on a separate dummy simple OS called xv6.

Comment: You can run GCC with `system`, of course.

Comment: @iharob but basically I am working on a system call on console, i.e. `ls` or `exit`, or even `wc` that takes in a file. So I am implementing a system call that tracks the time and cpu usage in executing a particular file etc. The system call would the output the results. Since system calls are much more low level and deals with `syscall.h` and more, I can't think of a better approach on this

Comment: With a little thought this riddle can be soved easily: Are there programs written in C which can start C programs? Hmm, are Unix shells written in C? The windows console? The Linux and Unix boot programs? Windows itself? Or some IDEs? Emacs? VIM? Can they start other programs?

Comment: @Olaf haha yes I know, but the thing with xv6 is that it does not come with complete C library and a lot of system calls are missing. Only a handful are available. Thanks for the examples anyway :)

Comment: @thedarkguy: What is "xv6", why is ther no tag/menion in your question? The question will soon be closed; more information and a **specific** question could have helped to avoid that and get an answer.

Comment: @Olaf ah, my bad on that! I am pretty new at stackoverflow, so there are things that slipped through my mind.

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7

Comment: Still, that's no reason to recompile a c program every time you want to execute it. You compile it once and then execute it. What you are attempting makes no sense, can you tell me WHY is it important to recompile the code every time?

Comment: You could probably write a function that uses `system` and `gcc` to compile the filename passed to the function (e.g. `gcc_compile("inputfile.c");`

Comment: @iharob let's put it this way, assume `x` is a system call, `x` performs calculation on .. maybe let's say the time it takes to complete a process, and this process is the C file we are compiling and executing. i.e. `x helloworld.c`, and in the system call itself, it would compile etc and then return the results.

Comment: Please stop saying you are implementing a "system call". Unless you are writing code that runs in the kernel, you are not implementing a "system call".

Comment: @jonathonReinhart I am writing code that runs in kernel. There are files `syscall.h`, `syscall.c`, `sysproc.c`, `usys.S` needed to be changed in the xv6 Unix-like teaching OS. Lol.

Comment: Wait. What the hell. You're trying to invoke GCC to compile a program *from the kernel*? You really need to step back, explain the overall goal you're trying to accomplish, and redesign your solution. What you're asking right now makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `system()` function given by the header `stdlib.h`, like so:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("gcc cprog.c -o cprog");
    return 0;
}
```

You can see here I am compiling a file called `cprog.c`.

Comment: `system()` is not given by `stdio.h`, it's from `stdlib.h`

Comment: I'll edit that...

Comment: Oh I got misguided.  Very sorry @MDXF

Comment: No problem, happy to help